# How can I make div with overflow: hidden overlap floating div?

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I am working on a site where a 3rd party in-line HTML editor is being used (CKEditor). I have the editor control wrapped in a DIV that is relatively positioned and has a z-index that places is at the top of the visible stack. The problem is that on some pages there are images that are floating (float: right) on the right side. Some of the CKEditor styles are setting elements overflow property to hidden (overflow: hidden).

So although my containing DIV has a larger z-index than the floating image the CKEditor elements are not overflowing on top of the image. This creates the a result that looks as if the top right corner of the editor has been cut out.

Is there a way I can work around this without trying to edit CKEditor styles? Check out this example sinario:

http://jsfiddle.net/nmartin867/StHJA/

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="floating">
    I'm floating!
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        Why am I not overlapping?
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.container{
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color:black;
    color: blue;    
}

.inner{
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
    /*overflow:visible;*/ <--This would work
    text-align: right;

}

.floating{
    color:black;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` causes floating elements to clear, just like `clear: both;` would. This has probably got something to do with it. I'm unsure of what you're trying to achieve though, you typed 'Why am I not overlapping?' in the floating box but that's exactly what it's doing when I open the Fiddle you posted. [example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Shfsk.jpg)

Comment: The JSFiddle looks fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: Thanks! I need *all of the child elements of div.container to overlap the floating element. The contents of div.inner are created by a 3rd party and I can't change it. So I am trying to work around that by setting postion to relative and a z-index. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried absolute positioning instead? Because you are floating a DIV that is not in the same container you want to overlap, it will position outside in the body itself. Also, you did not set the z-index for the floated DIV, so it will be layered behind because it is ahead of the other container in sequential order.

```
div{
border: solid 1px red;
}
.container{
height:300px;
position: relative;
overflow: visible;
z-index: 1;
background-color:black;
color: blue;    
}

.inner{
background-color:yellow;
overflow:hidden;
/*overflow:hidden;*/
text-align: right;

}

.floating{
color:black;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:green;
/*  float:right;*/
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
z-index:2;
}
```

I am not sure if this is the effect you want to accomplish, but this will position the first container on the top.

Comment: I had no choice but to remove the float and make the image an absolutely posited element. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do this but I am not sure if it applies to your situation.

```
.inner{
    background-color:yellow;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Alternatively when you want to override third party styles but do not wish to edit them in the third party application you can recreate the same css class in your own stylesheet and force it to overwrite the third parties by using important! eg:

```
float: none !important;
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing the overflow on the 3rd party elements causes issues with the tool. Good suggestion though. Thanks